# Not clear why this answer has been deleted

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/9095/856) is about good oils to use for someone with ischemic heart disease. My answer here is that one should try to avoid all oils and stick to a plant based diet, basically do as [Esselstyn is saying here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6pLRdawBw0), but without sticking to the extreme rigors like not eating any meat. The oil can be argued to be problematic on quite fundamental biological grounds.

While one can argue that a plant based diet without oil has not undergone the sort of rigorous testing one would demand for new drugs, the same can be said about olive oil. Olive oil has never been tested against no oil at all to establish that it is safe to use, that it won't cause the early atherosclerosis seen in the autopsies of young adults that are absent in primitive plant based societies.

My answer was as follows:

[All oils are bad for the arteries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_o4YBQPKtQ). Saturated fats are very bad, but even olive oil which has a reputation for being heart healthy, is actually bad for the cardiovascular system.  Studies that suggest health benefits for olive oil should be properly interpreted. It's not that olive oil is healthy in an absolute sense, it's just that it's less damaging to your body compared to the alternative that this is compared to (saturated fats).

In contrast, studies that have looked at the effect of oils in isolation have come to the conclusion that ordinary cooking oils all have a negative effect on heart health. E.g. [this study](http://content.onlinejacc.org/article.aspx?articleid=1137981) where the effect of eating olive oil on endothelial function is compared to eating walnuts and it is shown that walnuts can undo some of the damage caused by the olive oil and other fats.

If you take away cooking oils altogether on the long term, and then consider the effect on heart health, you find results that are orders of magnitude better than what has been found in studies that replace saturated fats by unsaturated fats. It was already known from older studies that people living in primitive societies where no or very little cooking oil is used, practically don't get heart disease at all, see e.g. [this article](http://www.ajconline.org/article/0002-9149(60)90007-2/abstract).  Other such studies looked at autopsies of US soldiers who died in Vietnam, it was found that about 80% had atherosclerosis while the autopsies of North Vietnamese soldiers showed that only about 3% had atherosclerosis. Such results cannot be explained by genetic factors, it is known that people from such societies start to suffer from the normal incidence of heart disease when they immigrate to the West and adapt to the Western lifestyle.

Experiments with heart patients have been performed by Esselstyn, as he explains [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6pLRdawBw0) he has been able to successfully treat patients who had inoperable cardiovascular disease (failed bypass, too ill to get another bypass and/or coronary arteries to diseased to be treated by stents) who had only about a year to live. The treatment was just sticking to a plant based diet free without any oil. Here you have to note that all the essential Omega-3 and Omega-6 fatty acids can come from vegetables if you eat enough of these (and believe me, you'll eat plenty of vegetables if you stick to his diet, as that's pretty much the only thing you can eat with the grains and fruits you are allowed to eat).

Another way to look at this is is from the "empty calories" perspective. Just like sugar, oil will give you calories without giving you any vitamins or minerals, apart from very minor quantities present in e.g. olive oil. The more energy you get from oil, the less room you have to get your nutrients whole staying within your total calorie allowance. Especially for older people who already eat a lot less than young people, this is going to be a problem.

If you eat only 1600 Kcal per day, then the 100 grams of fat will yield 800 Kcal son only 800 Kcal is left to get your nutrients from. Contrast that with someone like me who works out a lot. I eat close to 4000 Kcal per day, but I also get 100 grams of fat (I am trying to bring this down, it's not so easy to get most of the 4000 Kcal from carbs). This leaves me with 3200 Kcal a day from whole grain carbs which are packed with nutrients. If you assume a similar ratio of vegetables per amount of whole grains, this means that I'm easily able to get 4 times the nutrients as someone who eats just 1600 kcal per day.

The question is then how to prepare foods without using any oil at all. As [explained here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6OGmcRSsm0) it's not all that difficult.

---

This answer has been downvoted multiple times, which just shows how much we're all indoctrinated by the idea that cooking oils are an essential ingredient for a healthy meal.  to put all this in the proper biological context, consider that   we are ape species who originally lived in the bush in Africa. Our bodies are optimally adapted to such a situation. Normally we would not get arteriosclerosis, nor would be be using cooking oils.

If we use cooking oils extracted from just whatever plants we could find we would get arteriosclerosis (but if you happened to bump into an olive tree, and used olives then the damage would be limited). The human body has evolved to almost all of its energy from carbs not from fat. The amount of fat we can burn is capped at a maximum, when this limit is violated in people who have type-I diabetes, they get [DKA](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/118361-overview).

Are we now supposed to believe that olive oil that undoubtedly does have benefits over other oils, is the magical substance that is good for heart patients who in all likelihood would not have gotten heart disease in the first place if they had stuck to a no oil diet? Why not put the burden of proof on this hypothesis by demanding a clinical trial where no oil at all is compared to olive oil before we can say that olive oil is hearth healthy?

Comment: Could you please link to the question?

Comment: Actually, I believe it was probably downvoted because the studies don't really say what you are claiming them to say. The postmortem infarction review, for example, says nothing at all about cooking oils. It merely states that in all the reviews of Ugandan Negroes, only one had a healed infarct. You leap from that to say that "They don't use cooking oils so that's the root cause of all evils". The rest of the answer also relies on personal interpretation and soft science. (And no, I was not the person that deleted the downvoted four times answer).

Comment: I have downvoted your answer for several reasons (I think M.Arrowsmith's comments to your answer and downvoting of his answer were quite accurate) among other because your very strong claim *all oils are bad for the arteries* is (just) linked to a youtube video of a scientist whose claims might be interesting, but have never been validated in randomised controlled trials. When you write those strong claims, you should at least provide more evidence. BW

Comment: I've asked a question on the [Skeptics Stack Exchange](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/35076/20776) about this issue. Oils, I think have never passed a rigorous safety test w.r.t. heart disease, this raises questions about where the burden of proof should be on. Should we assume that oils are healthy and then demand string evidence to overturn this idea or should it be the other way around. Normally the way we go about in medicine is to allow soft evidence to raise questions about safety and demand strong evidence to prove that it is actually safe.

Comment: The exceptions are when we traditionally use a substance e.g. tobacco and alcohol, then we deal with that differently compared to e.g. marijuana. Eventually the science will catch up, but this takes time as the burden of proof is reversed when items have been used for a long time. And it's still the case that alcohol is legal while it would never have had a chance of being legalized had it been invented recently.

Comment: Interesting. I have seen your question on Skeptics SE, has it been reopened? Anyway, why should oils pass rigorous safety test (what kind of tests)? Otherwise you would have to do it for all aliments used in patients with CV diseases, no? Anyway, I think we have got your point: oil is bad, plants are good. But I still think that the proofs for your claims are weak and as suggested by M.Arrowsmith and JohnP rely on your own interpretation of some facts (or by picking up some studies among other suggesting the opposite). Hope Sekptics will give you the answer you are looking for. BW

Comment: @S.Victor I have an open mind about whether oils may be good or bad. I don't think that the safety of oils like olive oil  w.r.t. heart disease has been proven rigorously. We use it because of tradition, we've used oils for thousands of years, we then tend to deal with health issues differently compared to new substances. Just ask yourself if saturated fats would have been approved for human consumption by the FDA if this had been a new invention and we knew all the scientific facts about them?

Comment: @ Count Iblis. I appreciate your open mind. But do all olive oils contain the same amoun of saturated fat? Probably not. Some contain higher amount of unsaturated fat. Also, some oils contain anti-oxydants, etc... So maybe you can't see everything under the "fat" perspective. But you know what: should a "Count Iblis" come to my cardiology unit post-MI, I would make sure he won't receive the "Mediterranean Diet" (or similar) but some plant based food ;-) I really hope you will find some other adepts of your plant based food approach for CVD. But I am still not convinced... See you soon, BW

Comment: -Erratum to my previous comment: do all oils contain the same amount of saturated fat?-